# Hosting provider recommendation for site to accomodate a php http proxy

Tags: php, hosting, proxy, web-hosting, twitter

Recently discovered my current hosting provider doesn't allow php proxys.
Unfortunately for a site I'm building, there is no other option (Flash based web application to consume Twitter API)
Can anyone recommend an affordable hosting provider with this feature?

Answer (score 0):

I personally recommend that you use a dedicated hosting platform for this type of application, which can be quite data-intensive depending on traffic. However, in the past, I have had clients who use HostGator and other budget hosts for proxy-based applications with no problems (until their data consumption skyrocketed due to traffic, in one case).

For a dedicated host, I highly recommend ThePlanet and SoftLayer. If you're looking for something in between, a VPS can be nice. However, it does all depend on your usage and traffic.

Answer (score 0):

if you're setting up a public (anonym?) proxy then it will consume huge resources and dedicated might be the only option.

but if you only need to connect to twitter API for private use, then you can use any good shared hosting. most of them allow php to connect to external API.

usually, people use http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php

just find any good hosting that allow fsockopen